# Escape "<" and ">" as part of element attribute value in IE

Tags: javascript, escaping

I want to escape ">" and "<" inside an element attribute and unfortunately I could not figure it out.
It looks that by default in IE outerHTML is escaping ampersand character and once I try to escape ">" (replace ">" with "amp+gt;") the ampersand that is part of "amp+gt;" is escaped again.
Here is a sample code:

```
        var div = '<div atr="test & and < and >"></div>';            
        var $el = $(div);
        console.log("txt string: " + div);
        console.log("$el outerHTML BEFORE escaping: " + $el[0].outerHTML);

        var rgx = new RegExp(">", "g");
        $el.attr("atr", $el.attr("atr").replace(rgx, "&gt;"));
        console.log("$el outerHTML AFTER escaping: " + $el[0].outerHTML);
```

This is the output from this code:

```
txt string: <div atr="test & and < and >"></div>
$el outerHTML BEFORE escaping: <div atr="test &amp; and < and >"></div>
$el outerHTML AFTER escaping: <div atr="test &amp; and < and &amp;gt;"></div>
```

As one can see ampersand that is part of greater then escaped is escaped again.
Basically what I need to have is:

```
<div atr="test &amp; and < and &gt;"></div>
```

Would you please let me know what might be missing here and how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is in IE not Chrome, Chrome is fine IE is not.
I added IE to my question title.

Comment: why do you want the outerHTML to be escaped in the first place.  In _general_, if you're serialising the DOM so that you can then reassign it to an element, you're doing it wrong...

Comment: I used outeHTML to display the markup. I'm saving element html to backend and I need to escape ">" and "<" so those won't be considered as part of element tag.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `.attr` method to set the attribute and the contents will be escaped automatically:

```
> $('<div>').attr('foo', '<>')[0].outerHTML
"<div foo="&lt;&gt;"></div>"
```

NB: this is one of the reasons why it's good to use jQuery methods to modify elements instead of string concatenation.

Comment: Where do you execute that line?

Comment: @thefourtheye that was just a demo from my Chrome console

Comment: mmmm... I didnt know we can load jQuery in there. I have been trying to create fiddle to test these kind of stuff.

Comment: @thefourtheye StackOverflow uses jQuery so I just invoked it from the JS console of this page.

Comment: Thats pretty cool. And Do we really need `<div>` to get the div element?

Comment: @thefourtheye that's just there to create the element for demonstration purposes